# What are the most serve attempts for a single tennis point?

Tags: tennis, statistics, history, serve

In Tennis, you usually have 2 attempts for a service.

however under certain circumstances there are more serves made fot one single point, for example when the ball touches the net and then enters the correct T area or when an attempt is overruled by the hawk-eye.

What are the most attempts for one single point that have been recorded?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6w3dD7UUJac) is a video of Serena Williams serving four lets on a single serve.

Comment: What evidence do you have that four lets is the greatest number of attempts?